# Ignite Client connection and Client Cache

Tags: ignite

I would like to know answers for below questions:

1) In case if Ignite server is restarted, I need to restart the client (web applications). Is there any way client can reconnect to server on server restart. I know when server restarts it allocates a different ID and because of this the current existing connection becomes stale. Is there way to overcome this problem and if so, which version of Ignite supports this feature. Currently I utilize version 1.7

2) Can I have client cache like how Ehcache provides. I don’t want client cache as a front–end to a distributed cache. When I looked at the Near Cache API, it doesn’t have cache name properties like cache configuration and it acts only as a front-end to a distributed cache. Is it possible to create client only cache in Ignite

3) If I have a large object to cache, I find Serialization and Deserialization takes a longer time in Ignite and retrieving from distributed cache is slow. Is there any way we can speed up large objects retrieval from Ignite DataGrid.

Comment: have you got answers then please update the post as it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is discussed on Apache Ignite users mailing list: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Questions-on-Client-Reconnect-and-Client-Cache-td10018.html